# Div carousel Slider html css and javacript with buttons on a different section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a slider carousel that has a pic and text side by side. like the way, they implemented it on https://www.digitalsilk.com/  on the full digital agency section.I would appreciate if you can assist me with some techniques.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, like some code and what issue you ran into as an [edit].  See [ask] and creating a [mcve].

Comment: @Mbili Mwanza, you can use [SwiperJS](https://swiperjs.com/demos).